# HTTP 429 Too Many Requests on Windows 365 Cloud

Tags: remote-desktop

I'm using a Windows 365 Cloud PC via Windows Remote Desktop and getting a 429 HTTP Response code when trying to access a web site I'm working on.
I have no issues accessing the same site using the Host PC or mobile device in the same location and on same network so it appears to be an issue on the Windows end, but can't find out how to resolve.

Comment: The 429 Too Many request error is a response from the website, it's typically used for rate limiting (to prevent one account/client/network/user to request the resource too many times). While it's almost impossible for anyone here to theorize why that website rates limits that connection and not others, it might be that the same IP (the Windows Cloud public IP) is used by other cloud PCs to access that same resource, or that on your cloud PC you accessed it too many time (or too frequent.)

Comment: I know - which is what is confusing me more as I only get that issue from the Windows Cloud PC. Host PC doesn't have it (so traffic going through same ISP until Cloud PC) and mobile 4g connection is ok, so something is unique to the way the Cloud PC is accessing it. My site is a small business website so I can't see it being other clients accessing same resource. I've got a support request logged with Microsoft and I'll try the website Host too.

Comment: It's more likely the website dev to contact (that's you?), not the website host. The question here is what in the web server's configuration controls this rate limited and based on what it is.

Answer (score 0):

See the Azure article
[429 Too Many Requests errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/azure-kubernetes/429-too-many-requests-errors)
contains the explanation of some causes for the error
and suggests the following solutions which may pertain (or not)
to your case:

> Solution 1: Upgrade to a later version of Kubernetes
>
> Solution 2: Reconfigure third-party applications to make fewer calls
>
> Solution 3: Split your clusters into different subscriptions

For more information about these solutions see the article.

In short, the message explicitly states that you have exceeded the
limits of your Azure subscription.

Comment: That would make sense except for the fact it is a single website and I've not logged in to this machine for a few months so there has been no usage at all.

Comment: Consult the terms of your subscription and check which applications are active on your Cloud PC, to see whether this limit might have been exceeded even without any solicitation of this web app.